# Nginx ignore part of the URL

Tags: nginx

I want nginx to ignore the first 4 characters of a URL. For example, I want `/1234/test.html` to be served by the file `/test.html`.

How can I do that with nginx?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be achieved with a rewrite, probably inside the server block.

The regular expression needs to be pretty specific to avoid a rewrite loop, so careful consideration of all URIs is necessary.

If the four character prefix is always digits, this may work for you:

```
rewrite "^/\d{4}/(.*)$" /$1 last;
```

Notice the `"`s around the regex because of the presence of `{}`s.